# How to redirect output from dd command to /dev/null?

Tags: linux, shell, dd

In shell script i need to redirect output from dd command  to /dev/null - how to do that?

> ( dd if=/dev/zero of=1.txt count=1 )  2>&1  /dev/null

didn't work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to redirect only the standard output of the command do:

```
( dd if=/dev/zero of=1.txt count=1 ) > /dev/null
```

and if you want to redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null` do:

```
( dd if=/dev/zero of=1.txt count=1 ) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Specifically: You must first redirect `stdout` and then you can "copy" the new file descriptor to `stderr`.

Comment: I just want to ignore messages from dd command -- messages should not be displayed . thanks

Answer (score 6):

No need for a subshell.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=1.txt count=1 2>/dev/null
```

However what if there is an error? You could instead do:

```
err=$(dd if=/dev/zero of=1.txt count=1 2>&1) || echo "$err" >&2
```